# Android - Fragment findViewById in custom method

Tags: android, android-fragments

I made an applications that implements ZXing library for barcode scanner. I run that app inside fragment and I don't know how to setText inside custom method (onActivityResult). This is my code.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    //retrieve scan result
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (scanningResult != null) {
        //we have a result
        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        //String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
        codeET=(EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        codeET.setText(scanContent);
        }
    else{
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
            "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

This is what troubles me:

```
codeET=(EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.editText3);
codeET.setText(scanContent);
```

findViewById doesn't seem to work here. I also tried

```
codeET=(EditText)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
```

but I don't know how to make `myFragmentView` to work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: use `codeET=(EditText)myFragmentView.this.findViewById(R.id.editText3);`

Comment: post exception log if any?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK nope, doesn't work... still gives me an error: myFragmentView cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: method onActivityResult what class belongs? If to your fragment, just use findViewById(R.id.editText3)?

Comment: @Manivannan I don't think there is an exception log...

Comment: @cooperok I was following this tutorial: [link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-create-a-barcode-reader/) just instead of adding it to mainactivity I added it to fragment. that doesn't work either.

Comment: Try to do same as in tutorial, add method onActivityResult to activity, and call findViewById(R.id.editText3). And check your layout realy contain view with id editText3

Comment: i don't think that would work since editText3 is in fragment and not in MainActivity. Are you sure this would work?

Comment: I tried it anyway. It worked. Sorry I doubted you :) Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I normally create a member that stores the reference of the hosting activity:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private View mContentView = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        mContentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout , null);
        setView(mContentView);      
        return create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onActivityCreated(arg0);

        b = (Button) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.close);

        b.setOnClickListener(this); 
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

> codeET.setText(scanContent, TextView.BufferType.*EDITABLE*);

---